# How to use Python SecretStorage with GObject.timeout_add - Gtk3

Tags: python, gtk, python-multithreading, pygobject, python-keyring

I try to use SecretStorage in 2 Python processes, but when I try to update my Gtk.Window I get this message most of the time:

> RuntimeError: Unable to initialize SecretService: Did not receive a
>   reply. Possible causes include: the remote application did not send a
>   reply, the message bus security policy blocked the reply, the reply
>   timeout expired, or the network connection was broken.

Both started with **multiprocessing.Process**, this is working:

```
def get_data(self):
    p1 = Process(target=P1().update_database)
    p1.start()
    p1.join()
    p2 = Process(target=P2().update_database)
    p2.start()
    p2.join()
```

Problem is: this is blocking my Gtk Interface, Window is blocked,no other buttons are clickable.

Because of this I used a also **threading.Thread**

```
def on_get_data_button_clicked(self, widget):
    thread = Thread(target=self.get_data)
    thread.start()
```

This is also working, but I cannot see from the main window if process is still in progress.

So I added an Gtk.Spinner-Button to see the activity

```
def on_get_data_button_clicked(self, widget):
    thread = Thread(target=self.get_data)
    thread.start()
    GObject.timeout_add(200, self.manage_spinner, thread)

def manage_spinner(self, thread):
    if thread.is_alive():
        return True
    else:
        self.sync_spinner.stop()
        return False
```

Sometimes this is working, but most of the time I get this error:

> RuntimeError: Unable to initialize SecretService: Did not receive a
>   reply. Possible causes include: the remote application did not send a
>   reply, the message bus security policy blocked the reply, the reply
>   timeout expired, or the network connection was broken.

In the subscripts SecretStorage is used this way:

```
def get_key(self, key_name):
    bus = secretstorage.dbus_init()
    collection = secretstorage.get_default_collection(bus)
    if collection.is_locked():
        collection.unlock()
    items = collection.get_all_items()
    for item in items:
        if item.get_label() == key_name:
            return item.get_secret()
```

The problem occurs if GObject.timeout_add is called during the get_key() call.

And maybe it is also related to this question: [How to find a key by label from secretstorage collection](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44677371/how-to-find-a-key-by-label-from-secretstorage-collection)